# How is the standard view generated when opening Layout editor in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, print-composer

When opening the layout editor in QGIS3, the 21x29cm page with a map and legend on it is shown approximately 1x2 cm big on a vast canvas of grey nothing (zoom is 7.2% then), regardless of how I left and saved the Layout the last time. My screen is a 15 inch-ish one, so I first have to zoom in to really be able to see it.

Is opening in 7.2% zoom the standard behaviour, did I set some settings wrong or could there be some other reason for it?
As handling edits on the legend is reaaaally slow (many layers in project), this might be something that is connected?

Edit:
Indicated that I am more interested into possible reasons for the strange zooming value instead of explanations of how to zoom.

Comment: Go to Menu View > Zoom to 100% (Ctrl+1 on Win) or Zoom Full (Ctrl+0) or Zoom to Width - or use the icons in the toolbar.

Comment: Never happened to me... may be check if there is an item really really far away. To do that use the item panel. Or use the resize layout to content to make your layout smaller and then define it again to the rigth size.